# Nginx Ingress controller unable to access ingress from another workspace

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

Not able to access an ingress from a different namespace, my config details:

Created the ingress controller using `minikube addons enable ingress` , `kubectl get deploy -n kube-system` returns:

```
NAME                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE 
nginx-ingress-controller   1/1     1            1
```

I have a list of service and respective ingress at a **different namespace** (suppose cicd),
So `kubectl get ingress -n cicd` gives me:

```
NAME                     HOSTS                        ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
hello-ingress             hellohttp.ingress.host        10.1.2.3   80      9d
```

ingress details:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: hello-minikube
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: cicd
  creationTimestamp: "2020-1-1T01:23:34Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: hello-ingress
  namespace: cicd
  resourceVersion: "12345"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/cicd/ingresses/hello-ingress
  uid: 8d952612-11ee-11eb-a0ef-0800277ab13f
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hellohttp.ingress.host
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hellows
          servicePort: 80
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.1.2.3
```

I have configures the etc/host etc files as well. Please let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: Are you running minikube locally ?

Comment: yaa, to be specific using gitlab runner to deploy an application using helm chart. –

Comment: Are you using specific tutorial ?